# How to create a condition in my uploader so that only particular files are processed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have models `User`, `Contact`, `Appliance`, each of which has thumbnail images processed in `picture_uploader`. When a `Contact` picture is uploaded, it gives the option to crop it, unlike the other models. I followed [this tutorial](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3951-Cropping-Images-using-jCrop-jQuery-plugin-in-Rails-5) to create the cropper tool. My `picture_uploader` has:

```
version :thumbnail, if: :not_svg? do
  process :crop
  process resize_to_fit: [150, 150]
end

def crop
  if model.crop_x.present?
    resize_to_limit(500, 500)
    manipulate! do |img|
      x = model.crop_x.to_i
      y = model.crop_y.to_i
      w = model.crop_w.to_i
      h = model.crop_h.to_i
      img.crop("#{w}x#{h}+#{x}+#{y}")
    end
  end
end
```

For pictures that I upload other than in `Contact` model (e.g. in `Appliance`), I get an 'undefined method: crop_x' error as they are also trying to process the `crop` method, which shouldn't exist for them.

I assume the fix is to put in a condition in the `crop` method so that it only processes images from `Contacts`, but I don't know how to do this.
I believe I need to add an `if` block in the `crop` method so that the crop is only processed if the picture is coming from `Contact`, and skipped if it is coming from anywhere else.

I tried processing the `Contact` thumbnails separately, giving them `version thumb` rather than `version thumbnail`, and running the `crop` process there, but that broke all image thumbnails in the view for `Contacts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if method `crop_x` is defined for `model`, then the standard way is to use `respond_to?`. So replace your condition with this:

```
if model.respond_to? :crop_x
```